# R-squared in mixed model for each model

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a mixed linear model as below.

```r
modelF <- lmer(Gini ~ Years +(Years|Country),data1, 
        REML=TRUE,na.action=na.omit,control = lmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", 
        calc.derivs = FALSE,optCtrl = list(method = "nlminb", starttests = FALSE, kkt = FALSE)))
```

The output is : for each Country an intercept and coefficient (so if I have 100 countries, I get a model of B0 and B1 for each country).

they can be displayed using `coef(modelF)`

however, I wish to display the R-squared for each country.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R-Squared of lmer model fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327217/r-squared-of-lmer-model-fit)

Comment: No i already checked that article. it returns conditional and marginal R^2 for the whole model. What i'm asking is if I can get an R^2 for each model separately (i.e R^2 for Country 1, R^2 for Country 2...)

Comment: Hi there. You are more likely to get a good answer, if you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a small example of your data used.

Comment: You would need a separate model per country if you want to calc R^2 per country b/c R^2 is a *model* metric

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay so by running the above code, i'm using a linear fixed model with random effects of Years and Country. The output is similar to the output of a simple linear regression, I get a B0 and B1, and an r.squared. However, when i execute the coefficients of the model, I get the following:
For each country, I get a different intercept and B1 coefficient.
What I want is to see the R^2 for each country.
I tried to run a linear model for each country , but it doesn't give the same coef as the above model.